# What is the best way to make the same change to multiple branches?

Tags: git

Say I have two branches.  One of them contains a file, and the other contains a slightly modified version of the file.  I notice that both files have the same bug in them.  Do I have to go into each branch and fix the bug in each version of the file, or is there a way to do this to both files at the same time?

Comment: You could [cherry pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the changes from one branch to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cherry picking is the way to go for a one-off fix.

The steps would be:

1. Make the fix in one branch, and commit the result.
2. Record (copy to clipboard?) the hash of the commit you just made
3. Switch to the other branch

   ```
   git checkout otherbranch
   ```
4. Cherry-pick the commit that you remembered the hash for:

   ```
   git cherry-pick COMMIT_SHA
   ```

   Alternatively, if it's the latest commit for the first branch, you can just put the
   branch name instead of the hash.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve what you want is to check out either the commit where the problem was introduced, or the common ancestor of your current branches, commit the fix on top of that commit and then merge the change into both branches.

That way, both branches have the fix, branches aren't contaminated with changes from the other branch, and looking at the commit we can easily see which branches it has been merged into.

To illustrate this, let's replicate your situation:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/voo82358/git/playfixup/playfixup/.git/
$ echo line > file
$ git add *
$ git commit -am "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 9421b69] Initial commit
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git checkout -b release
Switched to a new branch 'release'
$ echo release >> file
$ git commit -am "Add release to file"
[release 4076727] Add release to file
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ echo master >> file
$ git commit -am "Add master to file"
[master d3ad097] Add master to file
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ git --no-pager log --graph --all --oneline
* d3ad097 Add master to file
| * 4076727 Add release to file
|/  
* 9421b69 Initial commit
```

So we have a file with different contents in each branch, and we 'fix' its ancestor:

```
$ git checkout -b fix-file `git merge-base master release`
Switched to a new branch 'fix-file'
$ sed -i '1iprefix' file
$ git commit -am "Add prefix to file"
[fix-file c84bd33] Add prefix to file
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ cat file
prefix
line
```

Now we just need to merge it into the branches, first master:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge fix-file
Auto-merging file
Merge made by recursive.
 file |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ cat file
prefix
line
master
```

and then release:

```
$ git checkout release
Switched to branch 'release'
$ git merge fix-file
Auto-merging file
Merge made by recursive.
 file |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ cat file
prefix
line
release
```

This leaves our commit graph looking like this:

```
$ git --no-pager log --graph --all --oneline
*   dd630eb Merge branch 'fix-file'
|\  
* | d3ad097 Add master to file
| | *   50c10de Merge branch 'fix-file' into release
| | |\  
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * | c84bd33 Add prefix to file
|/ /  
| * 4076727 Add release to file
|/  
* 9421b69 Initial commit
```

This may appear overkill for such a simple example, but when you start having to keep track of whether a particular fix has been merged into multiple branches, it becomes a powerful technique.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to fix the bug in one branch and then merge this commit to all your branches.

Comment: If you merge a commit, you effectively merge the entire branch. That is not always desired.

Comment: That's why you commit your fix as a child of the commit which introduced the bug @Arjan , then you can merge the fix into any branch which needs the fix. Also, it means that you can always tell if a fix has been applies because the fix commit will be on the branch. If you cherry pick, you can never be sure which branches have the fix, since all of the cherry picks have different commit hashes.